# ¿Cuál es el objetivo de la "data class"?

Tags: kotlin

En Kotlin se puede crear una clase como sigue:

```
data class Dragon(private val nombre: String, val type: Int)
```

¿Cuál es el principal objetivo de la `data class` en el Kotlin? ¿Cuándo debemos usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se creo para las DTO: objetos de trasferencia de datos.

Muchas de las veces creamos clases que sirven sola y puramente para pasar datos como por ejemplo la clase `Usuario` y crearlas son un dolor de cabaza para algo tan simple:

```
public class Usuario
{
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private int userId;

  public void setUserName(Strin username)
  {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password)
  {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public void setId(int id)
  {
    this.userId = id;
  }

  public String getUserName()
  {
    return username;
  }

  public String getPassword()
  {
    return this.password;
  }

  public String getId()
  {
    return this.userId;
  }
}
```

Aunque los IDE como android studio ayudan a la generacion de los getters/setters, es demasiado codigo para algo tan simple como transportar datos.

Kotlin resume todo eso a esto:

```
data class Usuario(val username: String, val password: String, val id: int)
```

Y automaticamente genera los getters y setters sin necesidad de tantos rituales.

Como ya se menciono al pricipio, los data class son solamente para clases que sirven informacion y ya, sin nunguna logica de por medio.

Answer (score 0):

`data class` es una forma válida de definir una clase de datos en Kotlin, por ejemplo:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

el cual creará una clase *Person* de tipo `data`, cuya estructura es:

- *name* de tipo `String` (cadena de caracteres)  y *age* de tipo `Int` (enteros).

Comment: adicionalmente se utilizan en las implementaciones de RETROFIt para el acceso a APIs , como un componente llamado POJO (Plain Old Java Object) la cual es una clase para almacenar/retornar  la informacion que es recibida con GET o enviada con POST. Este componente complementa al INTERFACE y SERVICE en las implmentaciones de RETROFIT